# Set range based content locations

Tags: vba, excel

Hope someone can help, I have a sheet I need to set a dynamic range to then do a looping function populating calculations against the correct variable.

For example I have a list of headers

Operator Name       -      Round Count      -    Cost

Bob

Ted

Fred

For the above example I want to find Operator Name and set it as the starting range then Select - End(xlToRight) & End(xlDown) then my current code loops through all of the Operator names (Bob, Ted & Fred) and inputs values in Round Count and Cost base on what is calculated.

The issue I have is that The first cell may not always be in the same location e.g.  Operator name on one sheet may be in Cell F100 and on the next F134. I was thinking of doing a Find and setting that as the starting cell but Operator name appears a number of times throughout the sheet.

Anyone have a similar problem they've solved or can someone suggest something?

Comment: How many times does Operator Name appear? How do you know which the correct one is?

Comment: 4 times, I only know base on the other headers next to it, One is a cost summary, one is a productivity summary and the other holds the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will loop through, finding all instances of "Operator Name", until it finds one with "Cost" two cells to the right:

```
Sub test3()
    Dim found As Boolean
    found = False
    Dim testRange As Range
    Set testRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    Do While Not found
        Set testRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(What:="Operator Name", After:=testRange, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If testRange.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Cost" Then
            found = True
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This formula is working to find Operator Name but it isn't giving me the cell address to continue setting the dynamic range. Any help?

Comment: As you said in the question, `Range(testRange, testRange.End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Select` after the loop will select the range you want.

Comment: Working perfectly now, Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use find to search top-down or bottom-up.

This code will search column F for "Operator Name" from the top and go down.

```
Columns("F").Find(what:="Operator Name", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Address
```

This code will search column F for "Operator Name" from the bottom and go up.

```
Columns("F").Find(what:="Operator Name", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Address
```

Both of them return the address ($F$1), you can change it to return row (1) by changing `.Address` to `.Row` if you want that instead.

Comment: Also ways to modify it to start after a certain cell if you need that.  The above will error out if nothing is present so you may need some error handling.

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through each of your rows and run an `IF` depending on the value, eg

```
For i = 1 to Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "Bob" Then
        'do something with bob
    Else If Cells(i, 1).Value = "Ted" Then
        'do something with ted
    Else If Cells(i, 1).Value = "Fred" Then
        'do something with fred
    Else
        MsgBox "My example on Stackoverflow had incorrect names"
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: The summary will do a count if function as the operator names appear a number of times (some 10-15) times in the data above the summary. I only want to do it at a centre place.

Comment: I understood the question as you wanted a specific calculation putting in on each line where the operator name is found.

Answer (score -1):

Try this function. It checks in all the sheet, your text can be in the Column F or in other column.

```
Public Function subFindText(FindString As String, inSheet As String) As Range

    Dim rowNb As Integer, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(inSheet)
    rowNb = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets(inSheet).Cells        ''Check in all the sheet
            Set subFindText = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(rowNb), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
        End With
    End If

End Function
```

if you test :

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = subFindText("Operator Name ", "yourSheetName")
    MsgBox r.Row & " " & r.Column

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

So you have four "Operator Name", then use FindNext and get them in an array :

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim FindRange As Range
    Dim FirstFound As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arrRng(4, 2) As Integer, i As Integer

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("yourWorkSheet")

    Set FindRange = ws.Cells.Find(What:="Operator Name", _
            After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not FindRange Is Nothing Then
            FirstFound = FindRange.Address
            i = 1
            Do
                arrRng(i, 1) = FindRange.Row
                arrRng(i, 2) = FindRange.Column
                ' find next instance
                Set FindRange = ws.Cells.FindNext(After:=FindRange)
                i = i + 1
                Loop Until FirstFound = FindRange.Address
        End If

End Sub
```